# How can I find a FNM-competitive affordable deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've played Hearthstone for about 2.5 years and I'm looking to get into Magic. Since my favourite decks in HS are control, I'd like to try to get into Magic with a control deck. I'm aware a large part of playing a control deck is knowing what to play around, and how you use/save your removal. I went to a con recently where I played a couple of games with the starter decks, and the Blue deck was a lot of fun, despite just eyeballing what seemed good and when to use it.

I've played through the tutorials in Magic: Duels and I'm planning on heading down to my local store on Friday to see what FNM is like. I'm aware of MTG Goldfish's budget decks section, but I can't see any control decks in there.

Are there any good resources for finding decks (in my case, specifically control decks) that aren't going to break the bank, but will get me into MTG with a somewhat competitive deck for FNM? I've found things like TappedOut which lists a ton of decks, but has little explanation of what each one is or how it plays out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current standard, a few decks I would look for are UW control, Mono-blue Brains and BW control. UW control utilizes white sweepers and blue counter magic.  Mono-blue brains is a control deck that tries to play sorceries at instant speed. BW control relies on spot removal to keep the board clear.

Another site you might want to check out is StrictlyBetterMtg's youtube channel. He does a lot of deck techs, with a fair number of them being budget.

Reddit also has good resources, with a particular subreddit for budgets: [budgetdecks](https://www.reddit.com/r/budgetdecks/)

For format information check out another question: [Magic The Gathering: Where To Begin](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/32815/magic-the-gathering-where-to-begin)

Comment: That's really handy - I like the look of the UB Budget Control (£35) from StrictlyBetterMtg's channel as it's (a) cheap, (b) control, (c) from what I can tell, reasonably playable :P Do you have thoughts/comments/criticisms on the deck? (That last question may be off-topic here, I don't know) http://deck.tk/02l02Z6d

Comment: @Joe I don't tend to play control decks, so I can't comment much on them.  It does seem a little light on finishers, but it *is* a control deck.